# iOS 7 BLE can't re-connect paired devices

Tags: ios7, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

On iOS 6, no problem, i can re-connect paired bluetooth devices

I use

```
- (void)retrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripheralUUIDs
```

and the delegate

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
```

returns an array of peripherals. I iterate over this array and connect with success each peripheral.

on iOS 7,

```
- (void)retrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripheralUUIDs
```

is deprecated.

Ok, i use a new method for iOS 7 :

```
- (NSArray *)retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:(NSArray *)identifiers
```

This method returns an array of peripherals. I iterate over that array and try to connect each peripheral but it's not working.

Log of peripheral returned by ios 7 method :

```
"<CBPeripheral: 0x176e5f50 identifier = XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, Name = \"Name\", state = disconnected>"
```

If i call retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers again, state of peripheral changes to :

```
"<CBPeripheral: 0x176e5f50 identifier = XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, Name = \"Name\", state = connecting>"
```

But nothing happens

I tried to use deprecated method which works on iOS 6 but it's the same. No connection.

Comment: A guy has reported similar issues in the Apple Dev Forums. His situation was solved after deleting the pairings. Can you try this?

Comment: @allprog. If i delete the pairing (in ios settings->bluetooth) and i restart app, pairing pop up doesn't show when i try to connect a peripheral. If i reboot the iDevices, it's ok, paring alert is shown.

Comment: This is probably a glitch in Core Bluetooth. The question is whether after the reset you can connect to the peripheral or not.

Comment: @allprog. After reset iDevice, i can paired and connected my peripheral once. If i restart app, no connexion.

Comment: What if you reset the device as well? As @tdevoy pointed out, there may be some issue with your peripheral's firmware rather than the app's code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to post how you're actually connecting to these peripherals for us to be sure, but there is no problem with the new iOS 7 method. I'm assuming you're passing in `CFUUIDRef's` (like we did for iOS 6) instead of using the new `NSUUID` parameter.

Here's what you need to do:

```
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:savedUUID];//where savedUUID is the string version of the NSUUID you've saved somewhere

NSArray *peripherals = [_cbCentralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[uuid]];

for(CBPeripheral *periph in peripherals)
{
    [_cbCentralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}
```

Note: if you're stuck in a connecting state, call `cancelPeripheralConnection:` before connecting the peripheral.

Comment: As some peripheral is seemingly returned by the retrieve API I guess the identifiers are good. There may be something else in the code but we need the listing to be sure.

Comment: @allprog word. Def nothing broken with the new api though...had to just try it out myself actually lol

Comment: Rest assured, I appreciate your tries, and express this by giving reputation. :)

Comment: @allprog back atchaaa

Comment: @tdevoy. I use identifier created with a string stored in user prefs. [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:strUUID]. I add this identifier to an array and call method retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers. This method returns an array of peripherals. This method works but i can not reconnect peripherals. I call [centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil]; but his delegate (didConnectPeripheral) is never called.

Comment: Sounds like you may have a firmware issue then. What's the chipset?

Comment: @tdevoy I use BlueGiga BLE 113

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure you are keeping a strong reference to the `CBPeripheral` of interest.

If that is done, but `CBPeripheralState` never changes from `CBPeripheralStateConnecting` to `CBPeripheralStateConnected`, just fully reload (completely turn OFF / ON) your iPhone / iPad.

Comment: the strong reference was my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't say much, but to connect to a the peripheral you retrieved from `retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers` you need to scan first and then connect.

Comment: I think that's wrong -- the whole idea of retrievePeripherals is to avoid the lengthy scan process.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't reconnect in `viewDidLoad` as at that time `CBCentralManager` state is Unknown

You should do that in `centralManagerDidUpdateState` method when state is `CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn`

Code :

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{

    NSLog(@"state - %ld",(long)[central state]);


    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {

        [self tryToReconnect];

    }
}
```

Helper method :

```
- (void)tryToReconnect
{

    NSArray * peripherals = [_centralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"savedUdidString"]]];


    if (peripherals.count > 0) {

        CBPeripheral * peripheral = [peripherals firstObject];

        self.peripheral = peripheral;

        self.peripheral.delegate = self;

        [_centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];

    }
}
```